# Python searching in 2 csv files

Tags: python, csv, search

I have a file called `Callnum.csv`, which looks like this:

```
SubjectID    Name      Code

66           Ioan     1101112
67           Attila   1134112
71           Lucian   1131312
72           Paul     1131212
```

and a file, called `F-V-Mnum.csv`, which looks like this

```
Group  PersonID    Code

1      78          1134112
2      18          1111112
1      27          1212131
3      59          1311110
```

I am trying to write a program, which parses code from the first file and code from 2nd file. If these lines are matching, the program should write in `final.csv` something like this:

```
SubjectID   Name     Code     Group   PersonID

67          Attila   1134112    1      78
```

I have tried the following code but it did not work:

```
import csv
import os

f = open('F-V-Mnum.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f)
next(reader)
f1 = open('Callnum.csv', 'r')
reader1 = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')
next(reader1)

ofile = open('final_file.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(ofile)
for line1 in reader :
        for line2 in reader1 :
                if line1[2] == line2[2]:
                        writer.writerow(line2)

f.close()
f1.close()
ofile.close()
```

Comment: classical "generator exhausted" issue.

Comment: quickfix: after `next(reader1)` add `reader1 = list(reader1)`: no more exhaustion (but still O(n**2) complexity, with a set it would be much faster)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, thank you can you tell me how to print and Group and PersonID? now i print only   writer.writerow(line2)